# Single page with multiple states controlled by URL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, redirect

tried searching around for this, but having a hard time coming up with the right terms for what I'm looking for.

**Basically, I want to be able to display a specific page state (show/hide a div) based on the URL.**

I have a single page that has 3 divs, and there is a group of radio buttons that targets the associated div, adds a show/hide class to its container, and also modifies the URL in the address bar to match the current view.

Example:

- localhost:8888/account/orders/history
- localhost:8888/account/orders/recurring
- localhost:8888/account/orders/feedback

The only file that exists is `/account/orders/index.php` though.

My markup for these buttons is like this:

```
<div class="sidebar__group">
  <div class="tab__group is--vertical" data-target="#ordersContent">
    <label class="tab" value="history">
      <input type="radio" name="ordersTabs">
      <span><a class="link">Order History</a></span>
    </label>
    <label class="tab" value="recurring">
      <input type="radio" name="ordersTabs">
      <span><a class="link">Recurring Orders</a></span>
    </label>
    <label class="tab" value="feedback">
      <input type="radio" name="ordersTabs">
      <span><a class="link">Rate Vendors</a></span>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

`.tab__group`'s data-target attribute is the container div that gets the correct show/hide div based on each radio input's value. The value is what is appended to the URL.

Here's the jQuery that controls it:

```
$('.tab').on('click', function(e){
  var targetState = $(this).attr('value');
  if (!$(this).children('input').is(':checked')){
      var states = $(this).parents('.tab__group').find('.tab').map(function(){
        return $(this).attr('value');
      }), string = [];

      $.each(states, function(index, value){
          var state = value;
          string.push(state);
      });

      var classes = string.join(' '),
      groupTarget = $(this).closest('.tab__group').data('target');
      $(groupTarget).removeClass(classes);
      $(groupTarget).addClass(targetState);
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).children('input').prop("checked", true);

      // Add the appropriate state to the current url
      window.history.pushState("string", "Title", targetState);
  }
});
```

What's strange is that when I'm running this locally, it all works fine. But when running on a live server, I get a "Not Found" error. I'm guessing this is because there's nothing actually at the above URLs. Is there a way to force it to go to the main index.php page?

Comment: You could try URL re-writing, I suppose. So you can turn `localhost:8888/account/orders/history` into, say, `localhost:8888/index.php?path=account/orders/history` or even several parameters `localhost:8888/index.php?section=account&subsection=orders&action=history` or whatever makes more sense.

Comment: Should I be looking into mod_rewrite?

Comment: Yes, if you're using Apache, then try looking at mod_rewrite. Additional term that can help you is `htaccess` - it's where you'll set up the rewriting. If you're using a different server software, just try `rewrite URL in X` or something.

Comment: Thanks for the tips!

Comment: So I've been able to redirect, but I need the address bar to remain the same. For instance, if I go to http://example.com/page/state the address bar should say that, but the page being shown should be http://example.com/page

Comment: Well, that's a redirect indeed, then, you need a rewrite. With a rewrite the URL does stay the same but you get something different from the server. See if [this article](https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/) helps.

Comment: I'm using: RewriteRule ^page/state  page/ [L] — but this is just redirecting to http://example.com/page

Comment: Odd, if that's a rewrite rule it should work. It's been a very long time since I've done anything with them but they shouldn't be redirecting, unless there is a flag somewhere. And I do know they aren't redirecting because I vividly remember how much trouble I was having when I was starting off and I had no clue how my rules worked, for they would just not show anything. Hitting `example/fake/path/1` wasn't resulting in `example/index.php?id=1` but _something else_ and I had no way of knowing what. A redirect to the new location would have made it easier to test back then.

Comment: Got it! Adding the solution above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution was to use mod_rewrite. Here's an example `htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} path/
RewriteRule ^path/to/state$ path/to/ [L]
```

`^path/to/state$` is the URL that will be rewritten `path/to/` is what it's rewritten to.